# How to auto-escape a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does such a thing exist to turn `This is a path` into `This\ is\ a\ path`?

Preferably with all the standard escape sequences such as `\t`, `\n`, etc.

It's easy enough to unescape things:
`print("foo\nbar".encode("unicode_escape").decode("utf-8"))`

---

I'll admit my first response to this question was use `pathlib.Path`. Anyone else looking at this, you should probably be doing that too. However, this doesn't work for the situation as I peered in more and asked questions. It literally has to be a tool that changes a string into its escaped in the style of \t \n \r etc. version. It's nothing to do with paths I guess. It's easy enough to just write a simple function, but I'm curious if something exists already.

The web has an encoder, so the request for one for the \t \n style isn't that crazy, is it?

http://www.utilities-online.info/urlencode/#.XVYwRZNKg5c

```
test this string
and this one
```

```
test%20this%20string%0Aand%20this%20one
```

Comment: In most Python contexts, spaces in a filename are perfectly fine, i.e. `open('this is a filename')` will work as expected.  How are you using this path?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need to add escape characters to spaces? This is not something you normally need to do when dealing with file paths.

Answer (score 2):

In python, there is actually a replace function that allows you to replace a character in a string with a different one as shown:

```py
string = 'This is a path'

for ' ' in string:
    string.replace(' ', '\\ ', 1)
```

Notice how in the third argument there is a digit. This is to specify how many characters it should change. The first two arguments are pretty self explanatory though.

The first is what you want to change. The second is what you want to replace it with. I understand you could just set the third argument to how many spaces there are however, it is more efficient and automatic this way as it detects it on it's own.

You can also use regex but I think this is the most 'pythonic' way of doing things since you don't need any other modules.

Also, I'm not sure why you would need to encode a string. You're definitely making it more difficult for yourself than it should be.

Comment: `Also, I'm not sure why you would need to encode a string. You're definitely making it more difficult for yourself than it should be.` -- Agreed. It's just an obscure use case and more of a curiosity. Again anyone reading this and working with paths, please look at PEP 519 and pathlib. It's what you want.